# SharePoint changes the Size of MS Office files when first saved, since Metadata is added. Possible to confirm that Content has not changed?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, metadata

Suppose we are migrating a set of MS Office files from (say) a Shared drive to SharePoint (eg SharePoint Online). Limited to Office 2007 onwards, so file extensions like DOCX, XLSX.

We see that the size of the file changes when it is saved to SharePoint - as certain metadata is added.
(Though file sizes of non MS Office files such as PDF or JPEG do NOT change).

These MS Office files are "containers" in which are placed a number of component parts - this situation can be viewed crudely by changing the Extension of an XLSX file (say) to ZIP, and opening it with WinZip.

For good sound integrity reasons we want to assure ourselves that the "File Content" component part has not changed.

How can we identify the component parts within those containers which represent the Content?
Are such component parts Invariant when when saved to SharePoint as described?

If so, are there any utilities which could analyse a pair of such files and confirm that the content is the same, or if it has been changed? Is there perhaps some checksum we could generate from both files and compare.

If no such utility exists what sort of environment would be best for creating one? - could it be done in VB.NET and/or C# for instance?

Thanks.

This previous post related to same issue, but does not provide the sort of answer we need. [C# - Hash contents of MS Office documents without metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616462/c-sharp-hash-contents-of-ms-office-documents-without-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic.
How can we identify the component parts within those containers which represent the Content?

> > > within the docx you will need to assess each of the content files. Please be aware that the files within a docx are compressed using deflate. So you will probably have to inflate them. This is not only the document.xml and the document.xml.rels file but also:
> > >       - the header xml files (can be more then 1) 
> > >       - header .rels files
> > >       - footer xml files (againa multiple files)
> > >       - footer .rels files)
> > >       - the media files (containing images)

You even have to check the core.xml file if SharePoint property demotion alters a field like title.

To summarise, you cannot compare the docx files at the docx level. You will need to unpack them and compare (use e.g. CRC32 or MD5) each of the "content" files.

I am not aware of utilities providing this functionality.

Note: if you just need to upload the files to SharePoint for archiving then placing them into separate zip files might be an alternative. This is of course only an option if you just need to store the content and do not expect the users to make any changes.

Paul